# Manually trigger Angular data binding for an input field (for unit testing purposes only)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm writing some tests for an Angular directive and I need to simulate user input into an input field. I tried to do this:

```
element.find('input').val('some value').trigger('input');
```

but it didn't work. Triggering `change` didn't work either. I know I can access the element scope directly with `element.scope()` and change it, but it seems more natural to change the input's value and let Angular do the data binding.

For what it's worth, I've checked out `input(name).enter(value)` from Angular ngScenario, and it seems to do the same as I did:

```
...
input.val(value);
input.trigger(event || (supportInputEvent ? 'input' : 'change'));
...
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way to test user input in this case?

(I made [a jsFiddler script](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLuW/1/) to illustrate the question)

**UPDATE**

I think some clarification is needed. I'm not trying to change the DOM nor the scope outside Angular realm *per se*. I have a directive that renders an input box bound to a property of the directive's scope. I'm writing automated tests to ensure the directive does what it's supposed to do, and what one test should do is to simulate some input so that the directive scope gets updated and I can assert that some behavior is performed on that input. As I mentioned earlier, I can change the directive's scope from the test code by using `element.scope()`, but I'd rather change the input's value and let Angular do its thing.

Comment: How do you test your directive? The way you trigger an input event looks right to me. You are doing this in a test file, right?

Comment: @ghiden I've already had my question answered - see below. Thanks for your interest, though. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After spending some more time researching and testing, I've figured out what was wrong: jqLite registers event handlers using `addEventHandler` and they don't get triggered by jQuery `trigger` function. My jsFiddle script wasn't working because Angular's script was being loaded before jQuery's (and therefore was using jqLite). I updated [the script](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLuW/6/) to load everything in the correct order so that Angular uses jQuery `on` function to register event handlers, and now it simulates changes on the input box and tells Angular to do the data binding.

My test code wasn't working for the very same reason. I fixed it by changing the scripts order as well. If I didn't happen to be using jQuery, I would have to trigger the event by calling `dispatchEvent` instead of `trigger`.

Comment: jQuery's `trigger` **does** fire handlers hooked up via `addEventListener`: http://jsbin.com/APEwimu/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/APEwimu/1/edit). This has been true for a [long](http://jsbin.com/APEwimu/2), [**long**](http://jsbin.com/APEwimu/3) time (1.2.6 was as far back as I decided to go). Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and [IE8](http://jsbin.com/APEwimu/4) - had to edit the script for that last, of course, because it wants `attachEvent`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's odd. Could you help me understand why [my first script](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLuW/1/) doesn't work?

Comment: I'm getting a $apply already in progress error--did you ever run into this when manually triggering an 'input' event?

Comment: @bennlich No, not that I can remember. Are you doing that in the context of unit tests?

Comment: No--that might be the difference. I wonder if digest cycles work differently there?

Comment: @bennlich I don't think so, but you shouldn't try/need to trigger the `input` event in production code. It's okay to do it in tests because you may need to simulate user's input (as I did back when I posted this question), but in anywhere else you should let Angular do its job. Perhaps you could post a question explaining your problem so the community can offer you a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I ended up realizing that I could easily change the model instead of the value of the view element (and let Angular do its thing).

Comment: Different issue, same symptoms on my side, using jQuery 1.9.1 & angular 1.2.2 : the change event was properly fired by jQuery, but not processed by angular, resulting in a scope not updated. Calling angularjs js files after jquery files solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

This is not right approach to do this in angular. You should do like this.

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLuW/4/)

Create function inside the $scope and change your variable value so that angular itself will update your input field as well as at all places where you have used(bind) this variable.

`Angular Function`

```
$scope.changeInput = function() {
    $scope.value="barfoo";
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. I'll update the post to make things clear.