# Need a Suggestion on jQueryUI or angularUI

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angular-ui

I am making a webpage using angularJS. I need to include a datepicker. Can I use jQuery UI (include jQuery too) for this or Should I use angularUI ?

Comment: I would just use AngularJS.  UI Bootstrap has a datePicker which I Find suitable.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery plugins and angular don't naturally work together very well.  You can use them, but you would have to do some manual wrapping of the plugin.  You're better off using angular-ui which will work out of the box.

For more info, check out the related answer ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1)

Comment: They included jquery, jqueryui.js,jqueryui.css files. so, $("#something").datepicker() will do the job, right ? so, why angularui ?

Comment: Because when you go to write that code, you will realise that there isn't a sensible place to put it in an angular application.  The controller should be separate from the view.  Only directives should update the DOM.

Comment: You could easily write a directive with `require: 'model'` + a `link` function that adds the jQuery datepicker to the $element. Key to make it work properly is to update the AngularJS model using `ngModel.$setViewValue(newval);` when the jQuery datepicker sets a value. Something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19168292/451480